# Scrapy Installation throwing error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

While installing Scrapy in Windows 10 through command prompt I get this message at the end. Please tell me what could have possibly gone wrong or how do I overcome it.

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\sarwar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Sarwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gigbscvh\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Sarwar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-xo9y3e03-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Sarwar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gigbscvh\Twisted\
```

Comment: What command did you execute for installing?

Comment: the command was --- pip install scrapy

Comment: Did you try `easy_install scrapy` ?

Comment: yes, I tried this as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with pip installation of scrapy in windows platform. I would suggest you to use Anaconda to install scrapy and use it. Anaconda comes with may predefined packages which are required by many other packages. Anaconda has always worked like a charm to me while working on python.

Comment: Okay, I have anaconda install and now what command should I type and where should I type.

Comment: this is the command you have to type in the anaconda prompt - "conda install -c conda-forge scrapy". follow the instructions here for further clarifications - https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows